# python can't import module after building with setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am trying to publish my package to PYPI but I am facing some issue with imports after installing the package.

My project structure (simplified) is as follows:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── graph.py
│   ├── mypackage
│   ├── resolver.py
│   ├── sql_node.py
│   └── topological_sort.py
└── tests
    ...
```

Once building and installing package, I can import modules that do not themselves import other modules for example I can do `from graph import Graph` but for modules that import from the other files in the project I am faced with "No module named 'src'" for example resolver.py contains import statement `from src.graph import Graph` and when attempting to import from this resolver class the error occurs.

I have tried various things such as using find_packages in my `setup.py` as well as trying to perform the same operation in my `project.toml` after moving all files from src into a package `mypackage` such as

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
include = ["mypackage*"]
```

But I am unable to resolve the issue.

##### pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires      = ["setuptools>=61.0.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Comment: You should move all the `*.py` files inside `src` to `src/mypackage/`, and build again.  From there to import your packages, use `from mypackage import graph` to import the `graph` module, or `from mypackage.graph import Graph` to import the class from the `mypackage.graph` module.  Please [reference the tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) once more to review what you might have missed.

Comment: @metatoaster thank you this worked but was also missing one step which was to remove "src." from the import statement as with the absolute import path it was still unable to find the module after build.

Comment: Try removing the `setup.py` if you are going to be using `pyproject.toml` method. In any case work on the tutorial again and verify that the tutorial works, and from there modify the tutorial code and structure with your own one step at a time and check where it broke.